# map layout highlighted points

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph, open-graph-beta

I am posting an Open Graph story. The posted object has `GeoPoint` array which correctly displays the route. The object also has a single `GeoPoint` property, which is selected as `highlighted point` in `Open Graph -> Stories -> Story settings -> Edit attachments`.

But the map displayed on timeline shows the route, and marks its Start and End point. The point I have provided is not displayed on the map.

En example of object's metadata:

```
<meta property="my_routes:points:longitude" content="15.966282"/>
<meta property="my_routes:points:latitude" content="45.777191"/>
<meta property="my_routes:points:longitude" content="15.958017"/>
<meta property="my_routes:points:latitude" content="45.777589"/>
<meta property="my_routes:points:longitude" content="15.953514"/>
<meta property="my_routes:points:latitude" content="45.786521"/>
<meta property="my_routes:current:latitude" content="45.798588"/>
<meta property="my_routes:current:longitude" content="15.947750"/>
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm wondering whether you can have ONLY a route OR a highlighted points?